# Why does `respond_with` not execute for failed devise authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After a successful authentication, I am able to override [respond_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with) as such:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def respond_with(resource, *)
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

However when authentication fails -- let's say with an incorrect password -- my `respond_with` override in the Devise `SessionsController` is not called. I know that for a [failed authentication](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L19) Devise then calls the [Devise::SessionsController#new](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L10). However, at the end of `DeviseController#new` the method `respond_with` is called.

So my questions are:

1) Why is my override of `respond_with` in my `SessionsController` executed successfully when authentication succeeds in [Devise::SessionsController#create](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L18)?

2) Why is my override of `respond_with` in my `SessionsController` not executed successfully when authentication fails in `Devise::SessionsController#create`? The controller action `Devise::SessionsController#new` finishes with the same `respond_with` method as `Devise::SessionsController#create`

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '5.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'haml', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.4'
gem 'pg', '1.2.3'
gem 'rtesseract', '3.1'
gem 'sidekiq', '6.0.6'
gem 'dotenv-rails', '2.7.5'
gem 'devise', '4.7.1'
gem 'letter_opener', '1.7.0'

group :production do
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.61.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'awesome_print'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: I think this is because your when authentication fails `user_signed_in?` will be `false` and hence your `respond_with` will not do anything. Did you try adding a `else` method and see it it works?

Comment: @cdadityang yeah good eye and yes I did try adding an `else`. For whatever reason the body of my `def respond_with(resource, *)` is just not existed when a user fails to authenticate.

Comment: Can you update the code of what you've added in your `else` statement?